How to argue formally about equality of suprema (in the context of Hilbert space norms). Kreyszig
Theorem (Riesz representation for sesquilinear form) Let $(H_1, \langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_{H_1} ), (H_2, \langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_{H_2} )$ be Hilbert spases and $$h\colon H_1\times H_2\to K$$ a bounded sesquilinear form. Then $h$ has a representation $$h(x, y)=\langle Sx, y \rangle_{H_2}$$ where $S\colon H_1 \to H_2$ is a bounded linear operator. $S$ is uniquely determined by $h$ and has norm $$\lVert S \rVert =\lVert h \rVert\tag1.$$
My doubt concerns the proof of $(1)$. We suppose that $S\ne 0$, then we have that
\begin{align}
\lVert h\rVert :=&\sup\left\{\frac{\lvert\langle Sx, y\rangle_{H_2}\rvert}{\lVert x \rVert_{H_1}\lVert y \rVert_{H_2}}\;|\; x\in H_1\setminus \{0\}, y\in H_2\setminus \{0\}\right\}\\
\color{blue}{\ge} &\sup\left\{\frac{\lvert\langle Sx, Sx\rangle_{H_2}\rvert}{\lVert x \rVert_{H_1}\lVert Sx \rVert_{H_2}}\;|\; x\in H_1\setminus \{0\}, Sx\in H_2\setminus \{0\}\right\}\\
\color{red}{=}&\sup\left\{ \frac{\lVert Sx\rVert_{H_2}}{\lVert x \rVert_{H_1}}\;|\; x\in H_1\setminus \{0\} \right\}=: \lVert S \rVert 
\end{align}
The blue inequality is clear, because the second $\sup$ is done on a smaller non empty set, for the second one I observe the following $$\sup\left\{ \frac{\lVert Sx\rVert_{H_2}}{\lVert x \rVert_{H_1}}\;|\; x\in H_1\setminus \{0\}, Sx\in H_2\setminus \{0\} \right\}=\sup\left\{ \frac{\lVert Sx\rVert_{H_2}}{\lVert x \rVert_{H_1}}\;|\; x\in H_1\setminus \{0\} \right\}=:A$$
Because we're just adding zeros to the set.

Question 1. Is this the correct justification for equality in red?

Edit after Lieven's answer
Since $S$ is a linear bounded operator we have that $A\in [0,\infty)$. First we prove that $A$ is an upper bound for the set $$\left\{ \frac{\lVert Sx\rVert_{H_2}}{\lVert x \rVert_{H_1}}\;|\; x\in H_1\setminus \{0\}, Sx\in H_2\setminus \{0\} \right\}\tag 2$$ but this it's obvious from the definition of $A$, we observe that the set $(2)$ is not empty because $S\ne 0$. It remains to prove that $A$ is the smallest upper bound of the set $(2)$.
Then, we suppose that exists $B>0$ such that $$\frac{\lVert Sx \rVert_{H_2}}{\lVert x \rVert_{H_1}}\le B\quad \forall x\in H_1\setminus\{0\} : Sx\ne 0.$$
We observe that for every $x\in H_1\setminus \{0\}$ or $Sx=0$ either $Sx\ne 0$ and therefore $$\frac{\lVert Sx \rVert_{H_2}}{\lVert x \rVert_{H_1}}\le B\quad \forall x\in H_1\setminus \{0\},$$ from which we deduce that $A\le B$, then $$A=\sup\left\{ \frac{\lVert Sx\rVert_{H_2}}{\lVert x \rVert_{H_1}}\;|\; x\in H_1\setminus \{0\}, Sx\in H_2\setminus \{0\} \right\}.$$
On the other hand we have that
\begin{align}
\lVert h \rVert :=&\sup\left\{\frac{\lvert\langle Sx, y\rangle_{H_2}\rvert}{\lVert x \rVert_{H_1}\lVert y \rVert_{H_2}}\;|\; x\in H_1\setminus \{0\}, y\in H_2\setminus \{0\}\right\}\\
\color{green}{\le}& \sup\left\{\frac{\lVert Sx\rVert_{H_2}\lVert y\rVert_{H_2}}{\lVert x \rVert_{H_1}\lVert y \rVert_{H_2}}\;|\; x\in H_1\setminus \{0\}, y\in H_2\setminus \{0\}\right\}\\
\color{red}{=}&\sup\left\{ \frac{\lVert Sx\rVert_{H_2}}{\lVert x \rVert_{H_1}}\;|\; x\in H_1\setminus \{0\} \right\}&
\end{align}
In this case the green inequality follows from the Cauchy- Schwarz's inequality, while the red equality follows from the fact that we no longer have dependence on $y$.

Question 2. Is this the correct justification for the green inequality and the red equality?


I would accept both arguments. "Correctness" of a justification is really about the power of conviction and different readers might require different degrees of explicitness.
If you want to establish more formally that the supremum of a set is a given number $A$ (where in your case $A$ can be another supremum) you need to verify two things:

All elements in the set must be less than or equal to $A;$
If all elements in the set are less than or equal to some $B,$ then $A\leq B.$

Let's apply that to your first red equality, leaving the second one as an exercise :-)
The first point is equivalent to the quantified logical statement
$$\forall x\in H_1\setminus\{0\}:Sx\in H_2\setminus\{0\}\implies \frac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|}\leq\sup\left\{\frac{\|Sy\|}{\|y\|}|y\in H_1\setminus\{0\}\right\}$$
But an implication is always true whenever its right hand side is true, regardless of the truth value of its left hand side. Here the right hand side is true by another application of the definition of the supremum.
For the second point, we need to have
$$\forall B\in\mathbb R:\left(\forall x\in H_1\setminus\{0\}:Sx\in H_2\setminus\{0\}\implies \frac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|}\leq B \right)\implies \sup\left\{\frac{\|Sy\|}{\|y\|}|y\in H_1\setminus\{0\}\right\}\leq B$$
This is where your observation about "adding zeros" kicks in. If such a $B$ is given, it must be nonnegative because based on your assumption $S\neq0$ there is at least one nonzero vector $x\in H_1$ that maps to a nonzero vector $Sx\in H_2.$ All $y$ in the set $H_1\setminus\{0\}$ are mapped by $S$ either to a nonzero vector or to zero; in both cases we now know that $\frac{\|Sy\|}{\|y\|}\leq B.$ By another application of the definition of the supremum, the supremum of all those $\frac{\|Sy\|}{\|y\|}$ is not greater than $B.$

I modified the question following your precious suggestions. As for the second equality in red, it seems obvious to me that it is so because there is no longer the dependence of y, is this enough or should we make other observations?

As before, I think that that argument should be accepted, and as before, if someone insists on formal logic you can revert to the definition of the supremum (twice) in terms of quantifiers

Thank you. Is the edit correct?
